# What npm script will run when package X is installed as a dependency, but not when I run npm install on package X?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am currently working on 3 packages: X, Y, and Z. Both X and Y depend on Z.

I am trying to set up a task on package Z that will fire off when it is installed as a dependency (so when X or Y run `npm install`), but not when I run `npm install` on dependency Z. I basically want to modify something in X & Y's folders when they install X. When I add an `install` or `postinstall` script in package Z's `package.json` file, then the task runs when either X, Y, or Z run `npm install`.

Is there an npm hook that does this? I am looking at husky and node-sass for inspiration and can't understand how they accomplish this.